# I want to train AI but it encounters an error of squeeze dim, how to solve?

Tags: python, neural-network, lstm

I'm works on LSTM neural network coding like this:

```
hist = model.fit(train, label,batch_size=16, epochs=1000)
```

**but it encounters an error:**

ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 16 for '{{node Squeeze}} = SqueezeT=DT_INT64, squeeze_dims=[-1]' with input shapes: [?,16].

this is the first code of model sequence:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
import numpy as np

batch_size = 16

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(56, activation='relu',input_shape=(window_length, number_of_features),return_sequences=True))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(56, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(number_of_features))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

may I ask for the solution? Thank you!

Im trying to make a training model for AI on LSTM neural network, the code should be running like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSSrz.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include a minimal reproducible example as well as the full traceback error.

Comment: How much do you understand of the underlying theory? For example, do you know what it means by squeezing, or what "dim" is short for, or how that relates to the data?

Comment: Im sorry, Im really new in this lesson

Answer (score 2):

try checking your model summary to see how the dataset shapes are flowing down the network and also check the initial dataset shape. It happens when a dataset mismatch happens. You need to have shape in the right manner. When it comes to dims compatibility any number can be compatible with 1 but not with other numbers.

(1, 1) is fine with (1, 16) and (16, any number) but (1, 16) won't work if (1, any other number than 16) or (16, any other number). Check the Numpy rule of broadcasting. The same goes for the tensorflow.

if = is a sign of compatibility then:

```
1 = any number
same number = same number 
one number not = same number
```